# Does Meillassoux's concept of a future god have any precedents?

Tags: theology

Quentin Meillassoux, Richard Kearney, and perhaps others have theorized about a God that has not existed in the past, does not presently exist, but may exist in the future, based on an ontology of absolute contingency. Does anyone know if there is a term in philosophy or theology for this concept? Or if it has any precedents? I'd like to investigate related history and fallacies, but can't seem to get any google traction.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE! Roberto Unger has written a book on the 'Religion of the Future'; but this I think is not quite, given what you have written, quite what Meillasoux et al are writing on.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with any definition of "God" by which this would make sense. Given that almost all definitions of God usually include something like "that who created the universe," I don't see how such a thing could only exist in the future.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery: All of that hinges on what you mean by "God". Certainly none of the people that these ideas would cover are going to be anywhere near acceptable to any form of fundamentalism. Meillassoux thinks of himself as an atheist (his PhD dissertation is title *The Divine Inexistence*). For why he ends up there, see his [eminently readable "Spectral Dilemma"](http://web.cerritos.edu/tstolze/SitePages/C4_Quentin_Meillassoux.pdf). Your "almost all" covers the majority conceptions of God, but certainly not the majority *of* conceptions of god.

Comment: @kingsbury: from what I can gather, it's an attempt to establish a theology for athiests - a kind of resurrection.

Comment: I suppose it's fair as far as it goes, I'm curious what answers people have. There are many problems with this line of thinking though eg (1) most religiously orthodox people use the word "God" to refer to something uncreated, so using it to refer to something that _hasn't even been created yet_ leads to more confusion and more difficult dialog and (2) Leplace said "I have no need of that hypothesis" about a God of the past or present -it's unclear what problem is solved by the hypothesis of a future-god.

Comment: @ig0774, minor nitpick: "fundamentalism" has a particular meaning in the context of theology generally (and usually in the theology of particular religions) that does not apply to many orthodox believers.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery: I chose the word fundamentalism somewhat carefully. In particular, because it refers to a definite form of belief. I was thinking of it particularly w/r/t Christianity and its application in *The Fundamentals*. "Orthodox believers," even if we restrict that to Abrahamic faiths still strikes me as too nebulous a category to pronounce definitively on (especially as most of those who are "heterodox" or otherwise non-orthodox don't consider themselves to be such).

Comment: @JamesKingsbery: Re #1: Its difficulty and perhaps starts a difficult conversation, but it being a difficulty doesn't really negate a history of people creating non-mainstream conceptions of god---often these are intended precisely to provoke such difficult quesiton. Re: #2 First, the Laplace story is pure legend. Second, nobody I know of has posited a future-god without some particular problem to solve, but that's not the same as asserting that there is only some particular problem that the hypothesis of a future-god could solve. In fact, the concept has been used in myriad ways.

Comment: I'd understand that *fundamentalism* as a descriptive label is usually understood in a pejorative sense; in the many varieties of Islam for example, there are certain beliefs - like *tawhid* - the unity of God - as being held in common; I suppose one could consider such a belief as being fundamental in the sense of foundational.

Comment: **No arguing in comments.** Take it to answers or chat.

Answer (score 5):

I've never heard a single term used to cover everything that might fall under this sort of umbrella. Its often referred to using terms such as "atheism," "atheology," etc., but those terms have other referents as well.

There are, frankly, quite a lot of precedents for this sort of thinking, depending on how far back you want to go, but the serious main source is Hegel, especially his thought from the period of the *Phenomenology*. An excellent overview of Hegel's rather bizarre theology is Deland Anderson's *Hegel's Speculative Good Friday*. Unfortunately, its a bit pricey. Hegel's God is, of course, not precisely the same: Hegel's God once was and will be again, but has to go through a period of non-existence. Hegel's ideas in this regard are somewhat based on the teachings of Jakob Boehme and Joachim da Fiore.

One might look at Ernst Bloch's *Atheism and Christianity* with his view of God as the God of Exodus, which he takes to mean that God is something *we* must create. There are some traces of this same structure in the early Lukacs, who was deeply influenced by Bloch, Walter Benjamin, and, indeed, a whole lot of philosophy in Central Europe during the Weimar Republic. A good summary of some of the trends can be found in Michael Lowy's *Redemption and Utopia*.

Similarly, Jacques Derrida should be mentioned. His version of the spectre is, in my mind, definitive for the form that Meillassoux's problem takes in the "Spectral Dilemma". See, especially, the edited volume *Acts of Religion*, his *Spectres of Marx*, and perhaps *The Gift of Death*. The French philosopher Jean-Luc Nancy might present another way out from the Derridean cosmos than Kearney or Meillassoux. Nancy has written some work on what he terms "the deconstruction of Christianity" that attempts a pretty radical re-reading of Christianity. Christopher Watkin's *Difficult Atheism* is a good attempt to summarise some of these trends in French thought.

Caputo's "weak god" and Mark Taylor's atheism share a fair bit of conceptual territory especially with Kearney (they are all influenced by Derrida, but in other ways). Again, not exclusively a future God, but some conceptual similarities.

Levinas version of Judaism as a "religion for adults," an almost, if not *actually* atheistic conception of Judaism is an important precursor for Derrida's religious thought and its out-working.

Its also worth mentioning Whiteheadian process theology, which does tend to have a conception of an actually-existing god, but not in a very traditional sense. God there is seen in the process of emerging as god, as not yet complete.

Finally, Nietzsche really has to be mentioned, not just for the obvious death of god stuff, but for his overall weirdly persistent and deeply affective relationship with Christianity.

Its worth noting that some of this resurfaces not just in philosophy but in forms of theology, such as the radical theology or death of God theology associated with Thomas Altizer and the theology of hope associated with Jurgen Moltmann.

Of course, most of what I've mentioned doesn't always get you to a god that is only in future, a contingent God---though Bloch and some readings of Derrida do. Then again, there's not really a single, straight-line path towards that conclusion. Both Meillassoux and Kearney adopt similar concepts but for quite different reasons. Hopefully that's a least some more sorts of things to Google.

Comment: As a first-timer, I see that I am not supposed to make comments like "thanks," but, just this once, thanks! This is very helpful for one way outside of academia. I will begin with Bloch, whom I've never read but who keeps popping up in interesting ways. The Lowy overview sounds useful to me, and I'd never have stumbled on it. Likewise the Anderson, though, as you note, Hegel's appears to be one of many "returning" Gods, so a precise term remains lacking. Perhaps something closer to Kurzweil's  "Singularity" with a bit of Mormonism tossed in.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look at it is not that the God of the future did not exist previously or now, rather that our concept of God evolves as we evolve. Our perspective changes over time in all things and so does our view of the Godhead. Our viewpoint is not absolute.

Swami Vivekananda wrote in the 19th century (*Complete Works*, V2, *Jnana Yoga*, *Maya and the Evolution of the Concept of God*, available here - http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_2/vol_2_frame.htm):

> We have seen how the idea of the Devas came. At the same time we know that these Devas were at first only powerful beings, nothing more. Most of you are horrified when reading the old scriptures, whether of the Greeks, the Hebrews, the Persians, or others, to find that the ancient gods sometimes did things which, to us, are very repugnant. But when we read these books, we entirely forget that we are persons of the nineteenth century, and these gods were beings existing thousands of years ago. We also forget that the people who worshipped these gods found nothing incongruous in their characters, found nothing to frighten them, because they were very much like themselves. I may also remark that that is the one great lesson we have to learn throughout our lives. In judging others we always judge them by our own ideals. That is not as it should be. Everyone must be judged according to his own ideal, and not by that of anyone else. In our dealings with our fellow-beings we constantly labour under this mistake, and I am of opinion that the vast majority of our quarrels with one another arise simply from this one cause that we are always trying to judge others' gods by our own, others' ideals by our ideals, and others' motives by our motives. Under certain circumstances I might do a certain thing, and when I see another person taking the same course I think he has also the same motive actuating him, little dreaming that although the effect may be the same, yet many other causes may produce the same thing. He may have performed the action with quite a different motive from that which impelled me to do it. So in judging of those ancient religions we must not take the standpoint to which we incline, but must put ourselves into the position of thought and life of those early times.
>
> The idea of the cruel and ruthless Jehovah in the Old Testament has frightened many — but why? What right have they to assume that the Jehovah of the ancient Jews must represent the conventional idea of the God of the present day? And at the same time, we must not forget that there will come men after us who will laugh at our ideas of religion and God in the same way that we laugh at those of the ancients. Yet, through all these various conceptions runs the golden thread of unity, and it is the purpose of the Vedanta to discover this thread. "I am the thread that runs through all these various ideas, each one of which is; like a pearl," says the Lord Krishna; and it is the duty of Vedanta to establish this connecting thread, how ever incongruous or disgusting may seem these ideas when judged according to the conceptions of today. These ideas, in the setting of past times, were harmonious and not more hideous than our present ideas. It is only when we try to take them out of their settings and apply to our own present circumstances that the hideousness becomes obvious. For the old surroundings are dead and gone...
>
> The great mistake is in recognising the evolution of the worshippers, while we do not acknowledge the evolution of the Worshipped. He is not credited with the advance that his devotees have made. That is to say, you and I, representing ideas, have grown; these gods also, as representing ideas, have grown. This may seem somewhat curious to you — that God can grow. He cannot. He is unchangeable. In the same sense the real man never grows. But man's ideas of God are constantly changing and expanding. We shall see later on how the real man behind each one of these human manifestations is immovable, unchangeable, pure, and always perfect; and in the same way the idea that we form of God is a mere manifestation, our own creation. Behind that is the real God who never changes, the ever pure, the immutable. But the manifestation is always changing revealing the reality behind more and more. When it reveals more of the fact behind, it is called progression, when it hides more of the fact behind, it is called retrogression. Thus, as we grow, so the gods grow. From the ordinary point of view, just as we reveal ourselves as we evolve, so the gods reveal themselves.

Comment: Does this relate to Kearney? I'm seeing a comment at the top that's kind of generic and then a really long quote dump.

Comment: @virmaior "...and perhaps others have theorized about a God that has not existed in the past, does not presently exist, but may exist in the future, based on an ontology of absolute contingency...Or if it has any precedents? I'd like to investigate related history and fallacies..."

Answer (score 2):

Terrence McKenna has a long diatribe in this direction that contains this https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/6588851-the-ultimate-singularity-is-the-big-bang-which-physicists-believe

I think his preferred reference to this notion is "The Philosophy of the Eschaton" (which needs to be kept separate from Eschatology in theology, which tends to range from Aristotelian teleology in Aquinas interpretation of Christianity, to the direct exegesis of the Book of Revelations).

Everything the man ever said in public seems to be on YouTube, due to extensive-if-not-excessive Dead-Head diligence, so I won't pick a reference or a version -- the search on YouTube would do a better job.  He tends to be a rich source of references, if you listen to him long enough.  And I know that he moderately favors a notion of ultimate logical convergence, that all experiences come together over time, which would lead to an omniscient being only at the last instant.

(So, for that matter would Hegel.  God would only understand himself fully at the culmination of temporal experience, after which point time would serve no purpose.)

Answer (score -2):

Hah! 
Can I ask you what was going on before the creation of this God? And what led to his creation?

Anything that has not been and then 'is' created simply can not be god. And the creator must have had some higher power than the creature, otherwise its unable to create it.

God, as a Godly act has created the universe 'from nothing & no things', anything that has a start date is obviously created.

To help better shape the idea of monotheism and God:

Say, "He is God , [who is] One,
God , the Eternal Refuge.
**He neither begets nor is born,** *key to what you are asking*
**Nor is there to Him any equivalent."** *key to help you shape a better understanding of God*

To say that God is One has four meanings: Two of those meanings are incorrect and two are correct.  The incorrect meanings are: 
The first incorrect meaning is that when a person says: “God is One” he thinks in terms of numbers.  He is therefore at error, because the Being of God has no second, thus it cannot enter into the category of numbers.  Don’t you see that those who say God is the third of a Trinity
The second incorrect meaning is to say that an entity belongs to a species or a member of a species. This does not apply to God, for it implies something is similar to God: But God is above all similarities, for He is unique.
As to the two meanings which are correct when applied to God:
The first correct meaning is to say that God is One in the sense that there is no likeness unto Him, since only God possesses such uniqueness.
The second correct meaning is to say that God is One in the sense that there is no multiplicity or division conceivable in Him, neither outwardly nor in the mind nor in the imagination.  Only God possesses such a Oneness (unity)."
From the book of Peak of Eloquence

Comment: How does this address Kearney's idea of a future God? That's not at all clear to me. Apart from that, I see some quote dumping.

Comment: @virmaior
Thanks for not deleting!
If I ask you how do you describe God, what would you say?
If I ask Nelson how do you describe God, what would he say?
...
We all have different definitions of God. If our basis of God is not close it would be as if I am talking about apple and he is talking about zebra ( not orange, I mean it could be that different!)!. Before answering his question I was trying to correct his understanding of God (Obviously to what I believe), that God is one without  a kind, not like us, not create-able and that a created God would be somehow divisible by time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing in the comment, but the question was about a specific concept of God being offered by a couple of contemporary philosophers. Your answer and your comment seem to be about something else.

Comment: I have read the guidelines...to my understanding if someone is asking question A, with B as its premises...before answering I have to correct his premises. Imagine someone saying 2=3 and then trying to ask a question. Correct me if I am wrong. I was trying to bring him closer to my concept of God...to help him answer the question. The only thing I can understand based on your kind comments is that "if someone to me is very off base, then just leave it be...because answering it this way looks stupid...". Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Did you read my comment that begins "I'm not sure ...". I remark that he's asking about a specific concept offered by Richard Kearney among others.  Whether you agree with that concept, I agree with that concept, or he agrees with that concept is not actually the question he asked. His question is (1) what is this view called and (2) does it have antecedents in the literature. All of that can be answered without trying to "correct his premises". It seems like instead, you are answering about *your concept of God*

Comment: so you are saying whatever premises anyone has, if I think its wrong, I should leave it be? OK, gotha!

Comment: No. I'm also not sure how you drew that conclusion. Clearly, if someone *makes an argument* that leads to the wrong conclusion, then it's okay to explain that how their argument goes wrong by pointing out a flawed conclusion. But this question does not make an argument. This is a type of reference request. If someone asks, what are Aquinas's arguments that God exists, it makes no sense to answer either (a) no need to use Aquinas -- go to Anselm or (b) we can ignore Aquinas because Dawkins. Instead, you might want to point them to the *Summa Theologica* or a diff. text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27517/discussion-between-virmaior-and-asma22).

Comment: As poster of the query, I agree "asma22" runs a bit astray, but I was interested to read the comment, so glad you didn't delete. Also, I did not notice before that there is a "reference request" tag, which I will use in the future.